# multi words PHP arrays replacement

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements[0] = 'slow';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

Ok guys,
Now I have the above code. It just works well.
Now for example I'd like to also replace "lazy" and "dog" with "slow" What I have to do now is would look like this, right?

```
<?php
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$patterns[3] = '/lazy/';
$patterns[4] = '/dog/';
$replacements[0] = 'slow';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
$replacements[3] = 'slow';
$replacements[4] = 'slow';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

Ok.

So my question is, is there any way I can do like this

```
$patterns[0] = '/quick/', '/lazy/', '/dog/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements[0] = 'slow';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
```

Thanks

Comment: Someone who can should retag this with regex and perhaps remove arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pipes for ["Alternation"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions):

```
$patterns[0] = '/quick|lazy|dog/';
```

Answer (score 2):

why not use str_replace ?

```
$output = str_replace(array('quick', 'brown', 'fox'), array('lazy', 'white', 'rabbit'), $input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just assign the array like so:

```
$patterns = array('/quick/','/brown/','/fox/','lazy/',/dog/');
```

which of course assign 0-4